# Get weight of a key in redis

Tags: sorting, redis, key, size, zset

I'm implementing a sorting algorithm using zsets on redis, and I would like to know how much space each key is using.

Is there a redis command to know how big(in Bytes) a set is?

Answer (score 0):

In Redis v4, you can use the `MEMORY USAGE` command to do just that.

Comment: No, im using 2.4

Comment: That's ancient - hard to tell... the best thing you can do is experiment and obtain empirical results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can calculate by yourself. In redis almost everything is stored by string except the integer. In zset every member has a score, If the score is Int32, then it is 4 bytes, float will be 8 bytes. and the member is a string, you can use the average string length to compute, for e.g. let say the average length is 10. the approximate byte number is 10. So a member is about 14 bytes. You can use zcount to get the size of zset. Then you get a min space It took. because Zset is maintained by skip-list and hash table, there will be extra space to use for these data structure.